# Python: frozensets comparison

Tags: python, set, comparison, set-theory, frozenset

consider the following script:

```
# multipleSmallFrozensets is a list of 7 frozensets of differenet number of string objects
multipleSmallFrozensets = [
    frozenset({'YHR007C', 'YHR042W'}),
    frozenset({'YPL274W'}),
    frozenset({'YCL064C'}),
    frozenset({'YBR166C'}),
    frozenset({'YEL041W', 'YJR049C'}),
    frozenset({'YGL142C'}),
    frozenset({'YJL134W', 'YKR053C'})]

# singleFrozenset is a frozenset of 3410 string objects
singleFrozenset = frozenset({'YIL140W','YLR268W','YLR357W','YJL155C','YHR067W',
'YAL008W','YBR255W','YFR027W','YGR148C','YJR122W','YJL204C','YJL093C','YLR244C',
'YNL003C','YBR111W-A', ...})

# don't forget that i is of type frozenset [just saying!]
for i in multipleSmallFrozensets:
      if i <= singleFrozenset: print "First option entered"
      elif len(i) == 1: print "Second option entered"
      else: print "Third option entered"
```

and the mysterious output is

```
First option entered
Second option entered
Second option entered
First option entered
Third option entered
First option entered
First option entered
```

These if-else conditions are checking for two cases a) i <= singleFrozenset, and b) len(i) == 1. The second condition is simple; however, I couldn't figure out the first condition where the cases that matched with are 1, 4, 6, and 7. I couldn't find a link between these frozen sets in these cases!
Any idea why?

Comment: Note: copying and pasting the given code will give different results due to the small slice I brought from the actual large 'singleFrozenset' variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set operator `<=` is equivalent to the `.issubset()` method. `A <= B` is true if and only if each element of A also belongs to B.

Comment: Just as I said: _each_ element of A also belongs to B.